# How to select no of rows from Data frame

Tags: r

I am reading CSV file and creating a data set
Yourdata<-read.csv(‘C:/Work/mydat.csv’)
This have five columns and nearly 100K rows and I want to select only few rows. Like, if I want to select only first 1000 rows then how can extract it in vector to do further processing on it.

Comment: Use an `nrows=1000` argument in `read.csv` to get the first 1000 rows. See `?read.csv`. If your question can be answered by "*read the help page of the function you're posting about*", then your post shows a distinct lack of research effort.

Comment: This is R 101. Googling for `select rows data.frame r` yields a number of results.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about subsetting the data frame. Check out [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) for more details.

For your question, the easiest way is by giving the index. Say, from the `diamonds` data set given with the `ggplot2` package, I intend to select the first 1000 rows:

```
library(ggplot2)
data=diamonds

subset_1=data[1:1000,]
```

For selecting some specific rows, use their row numbers.

```
specific=c(1:100,104,105,110,400:900)
subset_2=data[specific,]
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the *first* some rows, you should also consider `head`. For example:

```
head( data, 1000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects a range of rows.

```
sample <- Yourdata[1:1000,]
```

In order to get the full range of goodies provided by R on frames read [this page](http://www.r-bloggers.com/select-operations-on-r-data-frames/)

Note: I do not think this belongs to CV. I will propose to move to SO.

Comment: Seconded,as this is more appropriate for SO.

Comment: Please don't migrate RTFM stuff like this. There are most likely already numerous duplicates of this on SO.

Comment: @Roland Then perhaps close it, after OP read the answers? I would agree with that, also. Anyway, I don't have enough right to migrate, so, you can flag the question and it will be voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any data in the variable and then call the head function with that variable to represent certain data. A simple example of using a built-in data set is as below

```
a<-gapminder %>% select(continent)

head(a,15)
```